# Как сделать, чтобы слайдер не реагировал на мышку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

Я взял слайдер с сайта http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
Автозапуск и Увядать.
Когда заменил на свои картинки то у меня всё работает, но как сделать, чтобы слайдер при наводке на него мыши не останавливался?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.foot').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'
 });
});
```

```css
    body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
}


    nav{
        background-color:#B85900;
    }

    nav ul {
          padding:0;
          margin:0;
          list-style: none;
          }

      nav ul li {
          margin: 0px -7px 0 0;
          display:inline-block;
          }
      
      nav a {
          display:block;
          color:#FFD700;
          font-size:20px;
          margin-left: 35px;
      }
      
      nav a:hover {
        color:#05A4B4;    
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="GLAV.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="preloader.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
 <div class="menu">
 
 <div class="text_perehod">
<nav>
 <ul>
  <img src="gold.jpg" style="width:30px; height:28px; ">
  <li style="font-size:20px; color:#FFD700;">Golden horseshoe!</li>
  <li><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Меню</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Наше расположение</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="icons8-vk.com-filled-32.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="icons8-instagram-32.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="icons8-facebook-32.png"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><img src="icons8-твиттер-filled-32.png"></a></li>
</ul></nav>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- 

Слайдер в начале

-->

  <div class="foot" style="width:1600px; height:500px;">
  <div><img src="food-photography-sea-food-close-up-1024x677.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="1418305970.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="personal_502.jpg"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pauseOnFocus там же в документации все есть? почему не почитать?

Comment: я не понял, что там написано и как сделать

Comment: Первый коммент уже написал, поставьте `pauseOnFocus: false`